# Word JS Add-in - How to store user specific data on client machine

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am trying to develop word add-in using JS API. In my Office JS Add-in, I am trying to save few user-specific data on the client machine. I have done some R&D regarding this but most of the people are saying that save data in Cookie or HTML 5 Web storage. As per my knowledge Cookie is expire after some time and HTML 5 web storage also internally manage cookie. If I go with cookie or HTML5 web storage then "Is it the safe way in terms of security?".

Is there any alternate way to store data on the client system for Office JS add-in?

Please look into my question and let me know the proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did Marc's contribution answer your question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am also working on the same issue. I am going for a json approach, where the addin will create a json file on the machine or cloud. Then store and get data from that json file.
I'll get back once I accomplished that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation on this topic at [Persisting add-in state and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings).

Word, Excel, and PowerPoint support a [`Settings`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings) object. This is a collection of key/value pairs persisted within the document. Working with them is pretty straightforward:

```
// Read the settings collection from the document
Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function(asyncResult) {

    // Set a value in the collection
  Office.context.document.settings.set("MySetting", "MyValue");

  // Get a value from the collection
  let mySetting = Office.context.document.settings.get("MySetting", "MyValue");

  // Write the current Settings collection back to the document
  Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();

});
```

On the topic of HTTP cookies, they live as long as you tell them to live. If you set the expiration date far enough out, it is pretty unlikely that they'll even be *using* that machine when it finally expires.

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
```

Comment: Documentation also contains this 
```
Important: Don't store passwords and other sensitive personally identifiable information (PII) with the Settings object.
```